# Eliminar el desplazamiento hacia abajo de NotificationBar

Tags: android, android-studio

Estoy haciendo una App en la que necesito que sea una forma de Kiosk, está funcionando todo perfecto por el momento, la aplicación queda fija en la pantalla y no se sale, pero no sé como evitar que cuando una persona deslice el dedo desde la parte superior de la pantalla hacia abajo no se abra el NotificationBar...

¿Alguien sabe cuál es el código para eliminar o bloquear el deslizamiento de pantalla desde arriba hacia abajo para bloquear el NotificationBar?

No necesito ocultarlo, ya que lo intente y se oculta pero aún así si lo intento más veces se sigue desplegando el NotificationBar hacia abajo. La idea es que no aparezca por más intentos que haga.

Espero puedan ayudarme, desde ya, muchas gracias.